# Automatically displays the option

Tags: javascript, html

I have this table, where I show a select with  options but when clicking this it does not display the list right away. I have to click the input and then the list show.

How can I automatically show the list with just one click? Im using `x-editable`

```js
$('#table').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.task',
        title: 'task',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
         type: 'text',
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Empty!';
            }
        },  
        success: function(response) {
    
           $(this).parent().find(".Item").click();
        }
    });
    var ITEM = [];
    $.each({
        "Item1": "Item1",
        "Item2": "Item2",
        "Item3": "Item3",
        "Item4": "Item4"
    }, function(k, v) {
        ITEM.push({
            value: k,
            text: v
        });
    });
    
    $('#table').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.Item',
        title: 'Item',
        type: "POST",
        source: ITEM,
          select2: {
            width: 300,
            placeholder: 'Item',
            allowClear: true
            },
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Empty!';
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">001</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select2">Item2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">002</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select2">Item1</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope I have explained  well. Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, you need to add the `data-value` attribute, I believe there is no other way.

```js
$('#table').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.task',
        title: 'task',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
         type: 'text',
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Empty!';
            }
        },  
        success: function(response) {
    
           $(this).parent().find(".Item").click();
        }
    });
    var ITEM = [];
    $.each({
        "Item1": "Item1",
        "Item2": "Item2",
        "Item3": "Item3",
        "Item4": "Item4"
    }, function(k, v) {
        ITEM.push({
            value: k,
            text: v
        });
    });
    
    $('#table').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.Item',
        title: 'Item',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
        source: ITEM,
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Empty!';
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">001</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select" data-value="Item2">Item2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">002</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select" data-value="Item1">Item1</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either create your own data-type: [example](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/x-editable/inputs-ext/address/address.js).

Or another thing you can do, which does not show the list right away, but is less cumbersome: make the select inline. Change the editable for the select datatypes to this:

```
$('#table').editable({
    container: 'body',
    selector: 'td.Item',
    title: 'Item',
    type: "POST",
    mode: 'inline',
    showbuttons: false,
    source: ITEM,
    validate: function(value) {
        if ($.trim(value) == '') {
            return 'Empty!';
        }
    }
});
```

Added `mode:'inline'`

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with the `select2` version 4, stating we cannot use `input` tags anymore.

1. http://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3057
2. https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/979

It is recommended to use a `<select>` element, [documentation](https://select2.org/configuration/data-attributes) for reference.

Another [link](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2830) might be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with select2.min.js in version 4. So , You needd to replace bellow link

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.full.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks I didnt noticed